# Enums constructor static initializer

Tags: java

I am finding it tuff with enums. This is an example from Kathy Siera book :

```
    public class WeatherTest {

    static Weather w;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(w.RAINY.count + " " + w.Sunny.count + " ");
    }
}

enum Weather {

    RAINY, Sunny;
    int count = 0;

    Weather() {
        System.out.print("c ");
        count++;
    }
}
```

The output is c c 1 1. Understood.
Now I thought what if the count field was static? Would the output be c c 2 2 ?
Based on it, I modified the count variable to static.
But then what I see is this : 
Compile Time Error : Illegal reference to static field from initializer.

Searching on net I found this was some kind of a loop-hole by Sun and it allows static methods that can change static fields. Ok.. So now I use a static method incr to do my job :

```
     class WeatherTest {

    static Weather w;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(w.RAINY.count + " " + w.Sunny.count + " ");
    }
}

enum Weather {

    RAINY, Sunny;

    Weather() {
        System.out.print("c ");
        incr();
    }
    static int count = 0;

    static void incr() {
        count++;
    }
}
```

To my surprise, I get the output :  c c 0 0 !
Can anyone please explain this behaviour to me before I shoot myself?

Comment: Please fix your indentation and braces.

Comment: Extremely tuff question! All Java Programmers, Armour yourself :)

Comment: Before doing anything please visit http://www.suicidepreventionlifeline.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enum values can be thought of as glorified static fields ( they are under the covers ).

So, if your `Weather` were a regular Java class, it would have been something like this:

```
 class Weather {
   public final static Weather RAINY = new Weather( );
   public final static Weather Sunny = new Weather( );

   static int count = 0;

   Weather( ) {
     System.out.print("c ");
     incr();
   }

   static void incr()
   {
      count++;
   }
 }
```

You can see that `count` is declared **AFTER** both enum values, that means it is also *initialized* after both values are created.  Also, each function call that encounters uninitialized static variable treats it as initialized with default value ( for `int` it's `0`).

Because you never call `incr` after `count` has been properly initialized, you see its value as still `0`

Comment: I agree with sequence of execution, but one part confused my while executing this code is, on second call, incr() method showing count as '2'. As per your theory it should show count as ZERO, isn't it?

Comment: I am partially clear; can u please explain more on what happens when incr() is encountered in the Weather() constructor? Why doesn't it result into some kind of Compiler Error or Exception since We are trying to increment a value that is yet not even initialized ?

Comment: @thinksteep.  On a first call to `incr` `count` is uninitialized, so that memory location is assigned default value of `0`.  Then it's incremented 2 times by constructors, then REAL initialization to `0` occur.

Comment: Ahh! I see after two increments, the statement "static int count=0" executes and sets it to ZERO again. Make sense.

Comment: @user1500024 Look at JLS section here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3